# Using Powershell to get a list of users who have logged into a machine in the past year

Tags: windows, powershell, event-log

We have a few computers that are used in a lab for processing and users can log in directly on-site or via remote desktop.  We are trying to clean up the machines and decided to remove user folders for those who have not logged on in the past year.  I am able to use windows event viewer to find the information, but I haven't figured out a way to export the information I need.

I found this script which seems to do exactly what I need, except I'm getting the following error when I run it:  https://github.com/adbertram/Random-PowerShell-Work/blob/master/ActiveDirectory/Get-UserLogonSessionHistory.ps1

```
PS C:\Users\vmc\Documents> .\userevents.ps1
Get-WinEvent : Could not retrieve information about the Security log. Error: Attempted to perform an unauthorized
operation..
At C:\Users\vmc\Documents\userevents.ps1:48 char:29
+ ...  ($events = Get-WinEvent -ComputerName $computer -LogName $logNames - ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-WinEvent], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : LogInfoUnavailable,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWinEventCommand

Get-WinEvent : There is not an event log on the BIGBERTHA computer that matches "Security".
At C:\Users\vmc\Documents\userevents.ps1:48 char:29
+ ...  ($events = Get-WinEvent -ComputerName $computer -LogName $logNames - ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Security:String) [Get-WinEvent], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoMatchingLogsFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWinEventCommand

C:\Users\vmc\Documents\userevents.ps1 : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '.'.
At line:1 char:1
+ .\userevents.ps1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [userevents.ps1], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,userevents.ps1
```

I do have a log called 'Security' when I look at the Windows Event Viewer, so I'm not sure why I can't query this log?

Thank you for any help- suggestions to get this script to run or another way to compile this list are very much appreciated!

Script from the link (saved to userevents.ps1, called from powershell above)

```
<#  
.SYNOPSIS
    This script finds all logon, logoff and total active session times of all users on all computers specified. For this script
    to function as expected, the advanced AD policies; Audit Logon, Audit Logoff and Audit Other Logon/Logoff Events must be
    enabled and targeted to the appropriate computers via GPO or local policy.
.EXAMPLE
    
.PARAMETER ComputerName
    An array of computer names to search for events on. If this is not provided, the script will search the local computer.
.INPUTS
    None. You cannot pipe objects to Get-ActiveDirectoryUserActivity.ps1.
.OUTPUTS
    None. If successful, this script does not output anything.
#>
[CmdletBinding()]
param
(
    [Parameter()]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [string[]]$ComputerName = $Env:COMPUTERNAME
)

try {
    
    #region Defie all of the events to indicate session start or top
    $sessionEvents = @(
        @{ 'Label' = 'Logon'; 'EventType' = 'SessionStart'; 'LogName' = 'Security'; 'ID' = 4624 } ## Advanced Audit Policy --> Audit Logon
        @{ 'Label' = 'Logoff'; 'EventType' = 'SessionStop'; 'LogName' = 'Security'; 'ID' = 4647 } ## Advanced Audit Policy --> Audit Logoff
        @{ 'Label' = 'Startup'; 'EventType' = 'SessionStop'; 'LogName' = 'System'; 'ID' = 6005 }
        @{ 'Label' = 'RdpSessionReconnect'; 'EventType' = 'SessionStart'; 'LogName' = 'Security'; 'ID' = 4778 } ## Advanced Audit Policy --> Audit Other Logon/Logoff Events
        @{ 'Label' = 'RdpSessionDisconnect'; 'EventType' = 'SessionStop'; 'LogName' = 'Security'; 'ID' = 4779 } ## Advanced Audit Policy --> Audit Other Logon/Logoff Events
        @{ 'Label' = 'Locked'; 'EventType' = 'SessionStop'; 'LogName' = 'Security'; 'ID' = 4800 } ## Advanced Audit Policy --> Audit Other Logon/Logoff Events
        @{ 'Label' = 'Unlocked'; 'EventType' = 'SessionStart'; 'LogName' = 'Security'; 'ID' = 4801 } ## Advanced Audit Policy --> Audit Other Logon/Logoff Events
    )
    
    ## All of the IDs that designate when user activity starts
    $sessionStartIds = ($sessionEvents | where { $_.EventType -eq 'SessionStart' }).ID
    ## All of the IDs that designate when user activity stops
    $sessionStopIds = ($sessionEvents | where { $_.EventType -eq 'SessionStop' }).ID
    #endregion
    
    ## Define all of the log names we'll be querying
    $logNames = ($sessionEvents.LogName | select -Unique)
    ## Grab all of the interesting IDs we'll be looking for
    $ids = $sessionEvents.Id
        
    ## Build the insane XPath query for the security event log in order to query events as fast as possible
    $logonXPath = "Event[System[EventID=4624]] and Event[EventData[Data[@Name='TargetDomainName'] != 'Window Manager']] and Event[EventData[Data[@Name='TargetDomainName'] != 'NT AUTHORITY']] and (Event[EventData[Data[@Name='LogonType'] = '2']] or Event[EventData[Data[@Name='LogonType'] = '11']])"
    $otherXpath = 'Event[System[({0})]]' -f "EventID=$((@($ids).where({ $_ -ne '4624' })) -join ' or EventID=')"
    $xPath = '({0}) or ({1})' -f $logonXPath, $otherXpath

    foreach ($computer in $ComputerName) {
        ## Query each computer's event logs using the Xpath filter
        if (-not ($events = Get-WinEvent -ComputerName $computer -LogName $logNames -FilterXPath $xPath)) {
        Write-Warning -Message 'No logon events found'.
    } else {
        Write-Verbose -Message "Found [$($events.Count)] events to look through"

        ## Set up the output object
        $output = [ordered]@{
            'ComputerName'          = $computer
            'Username'              = $null
            'StartTime'             = $null
            'StartAction'           = $null
            'StopTime'              = $null
            'StopAction'            = $null
            'Session Active (Days)' = $null
            'Session Active (Min)'  = $null
        }
        
        ## Need current users because if no stop time, they're still probably logged in
        $getGimInstanceParams = @{
            ClassName = 'Win32_ComputerSystem'
        }
        if ($computer -ne $Env:COMPUTERNAME) {
            $getGimInstanceParams.ComputerName = $computer
        }
        $loggedInUsers = Get-CimInstance @getGimInstanceParams | Select-Object -ExpandProperty UserName | foreach { $_.split('\')[1] }

        ## Find all user start activity events and begin parsing
        @($events).where({ $_.Id -in $sessionStartIds }).foreach({
            try {
                $logonEvtId = $_.Id
                $output.StartAction = @($sessionEvents).where({ $_.ID -eq $logonEvtId }).Label
                $xEvt = [xml]$_.ToXml()

                ## Figure out the login session ID
                $output.Username = ($xEvt.Event.EventData.Data | where { $_.Name -eq 'TargetUserName' }).'#text'
                $logonId = ($xEvt.Event.EventData.Data | where { $_.Name -eq 'TargetLogonId' }).'#text'
                if (-not $logonId) {
                $logonId = ($xEvt.Event.EventData.Data | where { $_.Name -eq 'LogonId' }).'#text'
                }
                $output.StartTime = $_.TimeCreated

                Write-Verbose -Message "New session start event found: event ID [$($logonEvtId)] username [$($output.Username)] logonID [$($logonId)] time [$($output.StartTime)]"
                ## Try to match up the user activity end event with the start event we're processing
                if (-not ($sessionEndEvent = @($Events).where({ ## If a user activity end event could not be found, assume the user is still logged on
                        $_.TimeCreated -gt $output.StartTime -and
                        $_.ID -in $sessionStopIds -and
                        (([xml]$_.ToXml()).Event.EventData.Data | where { $_.Name -eq 'TargetLogonId' }).'#text' -eq $logonId
                    })) | select -last 1) {
                if ($output.UserName -in $loggedInUsers) {
                    $output.StopTime = Get-Date
                    $output.StopAction = 'Still logged in'
                } else {
                    throw "Could not find a session end event for logon ID [$($logonId)]."
                }
                } else {
                ## Capture the user activity end time
                $output.StopTime = $sessionEndEvent.TimeCreated
                Write-Verbose -Message "Session stop ID is [$($sessionEndEvent.Id)]"
                $output.StopAction = @($sessionEvents).where({ $_.ID -eq $sessionEndEvent.Id }).Label
                }

                $sessionTimespan = New-TimeSpan -Start $output.StartTime -End $output.StopTime
                $output.'Session Active (Days)' = [math]::Round($sessionTimespan.TotalDays, 2)
                $output.'Session Active (Min)'  = [math]::Round($sessionTimespan.TotalMinutes, 2)

                [pscustomobject]$output
            } catch {
                Write-Warning -Message $_.Exception.Message
            }
            })
        }
    }
} catch {
    $PSCmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError($_)
}
```

Comment: ensure that the account used to call the script has Admin Rights on the target machine as well as that the PowerShell runs elevated (run as administrator).

Comment: Strange, I made sure to run as admin on an admin account and it doesn't even get as far as before.  I just get C:\Users\vmc\Documents\userevents.ps1 : The specified query is invalid At line:1 char:1
+ .\userevents.ps1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [userevents.ps1], EventLogException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogException,userevents.ps1

Comment: the security log error is a clear indicator of insufficient permissions... currently its hard to help you without seeing the code. probably the best you post your scriptcode ;-)

Comment: updated question with code from github

Answer (score 1):

First you got this error:

```
Attempted to perform an unauthorized
```

And:

```
There is not an event log on the BIGBERTHA computer that matches "Security"
```

This clearly indicates that the account used to run the query against the remote computer does not have the necesssary permission. You can't access the and/or find the Security Log because of insufficient acces rights.

In your 2nd run with the right account and elevated shell you did get further, because you now get the error:

```
The specified query is invalid
```

That means you have been able to connect to the remote computer and read the security log but get-winevent could not execute the operation because the query syntax is invalid.

This part of the code builds the filter:

```
$logonXPath = "Event[System[EventID=4624]] and Event[EventData[Data[@Name='TargetDomainName'] != 'Window Manager']] and Event[EventData[Data[@Name='TargetDomainName'] != 'NT AUTHORITY']] and (Event[EventData[Data[@Name='LogonType'] = '2']] or Event[EventData[Data[@Name='LogonType'] = '11']])"
$otherXpath = 'Event[System[({0})]]' -f "EventID=$((@($ids).where({ $_ -ne '4624' })) -join ' or EventID=')"
$xPath = '({0}) or ({1})' -f $logonXPath, $otherXpath
```

The scripts works for me... but in the end you do not need the whole functionality, think this will help:

```
#Query
$XPath = "Event[System[EventID=4624]] and Event[EventData[Data[@Name='TargetDomainName'] != 'Window Manager']] and Event[EventData[Data[@Name='TargetDomainName'] != 'NT AUTHORITY']] and (Event[EventData[Data[@Name='LogonType'] = '2']] or Event[EventData[Data[@Name='LogonType'] = '11']])"
#Get List containing the dnsHostNames of the computers to query
$computer = gc [path]
#Run Query against computers and gather result
$result = @(
    foreach ($computer in $computers){
        #run query
        $events = get-winevent -LogName security -FilterXPath $XPath -ComputerName $computer
        #parse events as xml and extract necessary information, return object
        $eventobj = @(
            foreach ($event in $events){
                [xml]$xml = $event.toxml()
                $attrsht = [ordered]@{
                    TimeCreated=$xml.event.system.TimeCreated.SystemTime
                    eventId=$xml.event.system.eventId
                    SubjectUserSid=$xml.event.EventData.data[0].'#text'
                    SubjectUserName=$xml.event.EventData.data[1].'#text'
                    SubjectDomainName=$xml.event.EventData.data[2].'#text'
                    TargetUserSid=$xml.event.EventData.data[4].'#text'
                    TargetUserName=$xml.event.EventData.data[5].'#text'
                    TargetDomainName=$xml.event.EventData.data[6].'#text'
                    LogonType=$xml.event.EventData.data[8].'#text'
                    LogonProcessName=$xml.event.EventData.data[9].'#text'
                    ipAdress=$xml.event.EventData.data[18].'#text'
                }
                #return event object
                new-object -TypeName psobject -Property $attrsht
            }
        )
        $attrsht = @{
            Computer=$computer
            Events=$eventobj
        }
        #return object per computer containing all events
        new-object -TypeName psobject -Property $attrsht
    }
)

#As the property events is an array you can export it by using json
$result | ConvertTo-Json | set-content [path]

#If you want a csv we have to flattern the array 
$result = @(
    foreach ($computer in $computers){
        #run query
        $events = get-winevent -LogName security -FilterXPath $XPath -ComputerName $computer
        #parse events as xml and extract necessary information, return object
        foreach ($event in $events){
            [xml]$xml = $event.toxml()
            $attrsht = [ordered]@{
                computername=$computer
                TimeCreated=$xml.event.system.TimeCreated.SystemTime
                eventId=$xml.event.system.eventId
                SubjectUserSid=$xml.event.EventData.data[0].'#text'
                SubjectUserName=$xml.event.EventData.data[1].'#text'
                SubjectDomainName=$xml.event.EventData.data[2].'#text'
                TargetUserSid=$xml.event.EventData.data[4].'#text'
                TargetUserName=$xml.event.EventData.data[5].'#text'
                TargetDomainName=$xml.event.EventData.data[6].'#text'
                LogonType=$xml.event.EventData.data[8].'#text'
                LogonProcessName=$xml.event.EventData.data[9].'#text'
                ipAdress=$xml.event.EventData.data[18].'#text'
            }
            #return event object
            new-object -TypeName psobject -Property $attrsht
        }
    }
)

$result | export-csv [path] -NoClobber -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ";"
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!  The OS is Windows 10

Comment: uiuiui thats strange had hoped for really old machines ;-) what happens if you load the variable $logonxpath and execute the query: ```get-winevent -logname security -filterxpath $logonXPath``` ? btw. u use the same code as posted here, or did you modify it a bit?

Comment: running get-winevent -logname security -filterxpath $logonXPath did work, gave me a list of times an account successfully logged on!  I had been using the same code posted, no modifications.

Comment: so in principle you only need this query from the script or u need also help to execute it against the list of computers?

Comment: I need to know which users logged on.  The modification you gave just tells me a user logged on, but not which one.  This is the output: 9/30/2022 11:02:04 AM         4624 Information      An account was successfully logged on....  Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: hehe this is a view issue nothing more pipe the result to fl* = ```get-winevent -logname security -filterxpath $logonXPath | fl *``` then u see more ;-)

Comment: I don't see any user IDs in the info...It looks like maybe they are blank when it's a server service?  But this brings up the same issue I had with just looking through event logs, I just need a list of user names of people who have logged on in the last year and scrolling through a year's worth of log ons to pick out the user names just doesn't make sense.  Thanks for your help though!

Comment: give some minutes I add a code sample to my answer which gives you what you want

Comment: Thanks for helping!  I ran the code there and it ran successfully, but I'm not sure how to get the results in new-object displayed?  I tried Write-Host ($results | Format-Table | Out-String) but couldn't get that formatted so that I could read it.  $res | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation "test.csv" gave me System.Object[] in the csv.  Sorry, I don't have experience scripting for powershell so I'm not sure how to see the output in $results

Comment: hehe true, because the property events is an array. I'll update the answer

Comment: Sorry, I'm still having issues!  I get the error "Cannot perform operation because the wildcard path [path] did not resolve to a file."  I tried changing [path] to "testUSEREXPORT.csv" but got a blank file.

Comment: yes [path] is only a placeholder where you have to enter your path - but please enter the full path not only the filename, e.g.: C:\myfile.txt